# PostSharp with Caliburn.Micro throwing exception on build

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, caliburn.micro, postsharp

I've just installed PostSharp 3.0.32.0 into my .net 4.5 WPF solution, and I am getting the following exception:

```
Error 13 Unhandled exception (3.0.32.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Cannot find a method named 'NotifyOfPropertyChange' with signature '(string) : void' in scope 'Caliburn.Micro.Conductor`1::Collection::OneActive' (module = 'Caliburn.Micro.dll').
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.MethodDefDeclarationCollection.GetMethod(String name, IMethodSignature signature, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodRefDeclaration.GetMethodDefinition(BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.IndexGenericInstancesTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation) C:\Projects\nextgen\NextGen.Client\POSTSHARP NextGen.Client
```

We are using Caliburn.Micro 1.5.2 with Autofac. We are also using PropertyChanged.Fody and Validar.Fody.

I had created some basic aspects and applied them, but have since removed them. The error appears unless I disable PostSharp on my WPF project.

I have tried to replicate it in a simple sample project created with Caliburn.Micro.Start (modified only slightly to use a OneActive conductor), PostSharp and PropertyChanged.Fody installed, but to no avail - it builds without issue.

Has anyone run across this issue before?

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: Does the same error occur if you disable fody?

Comment: If I remove the PropertyChanged weaver the problem disappears. However in my sample project I have the propertyChanged weaver enabled along with PostSharp, and do not experience the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to chase down a repro for you Simon - there is something specific in my WPF project that is causing it, but my basic repro does not trigger the same behaviour.

Comment: in your stand alone project did you use a Conductor<T>?

Comment: Yes, I constructed the same basic setup as the problem project.

Comment: [Here is the sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkohnkrqfm63fki/WpfApplication2.zip)

Comment: Andrew. is that project meant to reproduce the issue. on my machine it compiles.

Comment: No sorry Simon, that is the project in which I tried to reproduce the issue and failed to, I was just supplying it for completeness - it is the same basic setup as the problem project. At the moment I am using Fody in my WPF client project and PostSharp in a seperate class library project in the same solution - keeping them both isolated from each other has solved my problem for the moment.

Comment: If there is anything you'd like from the problem project I'd be happy to supply it, I just can't supply the project itself.

Comment: does it only happen on mondays? https://twitter.com/gfraiteur/status/207722639383470080

Comment: I can confirm it happens on both Mondays **and** Wednesdays. I'll have to get back to you about the rest of the days though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to solve the problem in this case by isolating the PostSharp code in its own assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out why postsharp is looking for the NotifyPropertyChanged method in the first place. Fody should be the one doing that. Have you configured PostSharp to do the NotifyPropertyChanged implementation as well as Fody?

My guess is that the problem lies in using the 2 IL re-writers and them not playing nice together. I would remove PostSharp and use Fody only.

Comment: No, the NPC module of postsharp only comes with the 'ultimate' edition, I am using the free ed. Fody only means that I need to rewrite the IL myself using Mono.Cecil, which will take much longer than writing simple aspects with PostSharp.

Comment: note that on mondays the free edition acts like the pro edition https://twitter.com/gfraiteur/status/207722639383470080